# TPL and Exception Handling

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, continuations

All, there are many question on the above topic but I believe this is sufficiently different to warrant a new question. I have the following `Task` and a continuation to deal with a variety of task `Status`; `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`, `TaskStatus.Canceled` and of course the `AggregateException` via `TaskStatus.Faulted`. The code looks like

```
Task<bool> asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
    asyncMethod(uiScheduler, token, someBoolean), token);

asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Check task status.
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            if (asyncTask.Result)
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            if (task.Exception != null)
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = task.Exception.InnerException.Message;
            else
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = "Operation failed!";
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This all works well, but I am concerned whether or not I am doing this right, as there is the possibility of an `AggregateException` being thrown from within the continuation - what then?

I do not want to `Wait` on my `asyncTask` nor the continuation as this will block the return to the UI Thread. To catch any exceptions thrown from within a continuation can't mean I have to do something like this surely

```
Task parentTask = Task.Factory.startNew(() => 
    {
        Task<bool> asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
            asyncMethod(uiScheduler, token, someBoolean), token);

        Task continueTask = asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                // My continuation stuff...   
            }

        try
        {
            continueTask.Wait();
        }
        catch(AggregateException aggEx)
        { 
            // Some handling here...
        }
    });
```

would this even work? What is best practice here?

As always, thanks for your time.

Comment: I've seen tasks that "ran to completion" when in fact they threw an AggregateException. That kind of error handling doesn't work. Why not just use a try/catch?

Comment: You mean in the method that is called on the background thread, or in the actual continuation delegate method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *can* use traditional try/catch within your delegates watching for `AggregateException` or you can chain on specific continuations that will only ever run if the antecedent has faulted using the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` option. The latter approach allows for very clean task workflows to be defined. For example:

```
Task myRootTask = ....;

myRootTask.ContinueWith(rootAntecdent =>
{
    // this will only be executed if the antecedent completed successfully, no need to check for faults
},
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

myRootTask.ContinueWith(rootAntecedent =>
{
    // this will only be executed if the antecedent faulted, observe exception and handle accordingly
},
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Answer (score 2):

Msdn has a fairly well written "How to" on the subject: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614.aspx)

You will notice they simply use a `try/catch(AggregateException`) block, then filter the exception they know how to handle in `ae.Handle(lambda)` and make the app stop if there are some left that aren't handleable.

Comment: I am aware of examples like the ones your link provides and do not have an issue with eception handling _this way_. My issue is how to handle exeptions thrown from continuations without enclosing the entire continuation delegate with a try catch, then again this might be the only way. I want to know best paractice for real world code, not Microsoft toy code best practice. Cheers.

Comment: The OP wants to know how to do this without using Wait. The examples all Wait for the Task. Try this[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx] link.